# How to ssh to a remote linux server using python script and be able to execute command as the user specified while using ssh in the python script

Tags: python

I have to monitor 8 to 9 servers. I am thinking of creating a python script that will create a menu to login to any servers and after using ssh to login to the server, can I be able to execute commands in the server as the 'user' specified in the ssh. Please see the command below in python. I am importing 'os' to execute the bash commands.

```
 server_login = "ssh {}@{}".format('user_name','10.111.0.10')
            os.system(server_login)
```

Comment: Then instead of just `ssh <user>@<host>` do `ssh <user>@<host> <command>`. If you don't specify a command then it will do an interactive login.

Answer (score 3):

you can install `paramiko` for this

`pip install paramiko`

then the script can be like

```
import paramiko

host = "google.com"
port = 22
username = "user"
password = "Pass"

command = "ls"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

If paramiko isn't your style, I can think of two other ways to do this:

run the command: `ssh <user>@<host> <command>` for every command via `os.system` calls.  This gets rather cumbersome when you're using passwords for SSH instead of keys.

run `ssh <user>@<host>` with the `subprocess` library instead so you can get access to stdin and stdout and run multiple commands in the session

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','root@example.com'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("ls\n")
print(p.stdout.read())
```